# How to include MFC in a CMake ninja project build with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, cmake, mfc, visual-studio-2019, ninja

I have a C++ project structure like:

```
mfc_ninja
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── source.cpp
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

project(mylib)

add_definitions(-D_AFXDLL)
set(CMAKE_MFC_FLAG 2)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED source.cpp)
```

`source.cpp`

```
#include <afxwin.h>
```

I open the directory `mfc_ninja` with Visual Studio 2019. Then I go to the menu *Project* and *Generate cache* which works as expected. When I try to build the project, I get the error:

```
Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'afxwin.h': No such file or directory
```

[image]

I have no experience with MFC. I want to port existing Visual Studio Solutions to pure CMake. For executables I found that you have to define `add_executable` with `WIN32`. But for `add_library` this does not exist.

How can I build a library with pure CMake against MFC?

---

I updated the `CMakeLists.txt` to use `FindMFC` as stated in the comments:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

project(mylib)

find_package(MFC REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "MFC_FOUND: ${MFC_FOUND}")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED source.cpp)
```

The outputs tells me that MFC is not found by it:

```
1> CMake generation started for default configuration: 'x64-Debug'.
1> Command line: "cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\benjamin.buch\source\repos\mfc_ninja\out\install\x64-Debug" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\benjamin.buch\source\repos\mfc_ninja" 2>&1"
1> Working directory: C:\Users\benjamin.buch\source\repos\mfc_ninja\out\build\x64-Debug
1> [CMake] -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29915.0
1> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29915.0
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- Looking for MFC
1> [CMake] -- Looking for MFC - not found
1> [CMake] -- MFC_FOUND: NO
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done
1> [CMake] -- Generating done
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/benjamin.buch/source/repos/mfc_ninja/out/build/x64-Debug
1> Extracted CMake variables.
1> Extracted source files and headers.
1> Extracted code model.
1> Extracted includes paths.
1> CMake generation finished.
```

What also confuses me a bit is that despite `REQUIRED` this does not abort with an error message.

Comment: In my opinion, since CMake is usually used for cross-platform code, and a MFC app can't run on Linux or other OS, it's actually better to use VS directly.

Comment: @kiner_shah We are currently refactoring our code to get rid of exactly that. MFC should be out in the long run. A new project currently exists only as CMake version. But there is now an indirect dependency to this legacy code.

Comment: I suggest creating a simple MFC app via VS and seeing what are the settings there (include paths, libraries, etc.). Then copying those paths in CMake and testing.

Comment: The project is failing to set the ATL/MFC include directory. I don't know how that's done, but maybe a simple [`FindMFC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindMFC.html) is sufficient.

Comment: @kiner_shah The (hypothetical) idea to use CMake for cross-platform code is rarely the driving motivation to use CMake. It provides benefits for single-platform development, too. You'll learn to appreciate it if you were ever tasked to merge XML-based MSBuild scripts, and resolve merge conflicts. I lost a fair share of my mind over doing this in the past.

Comment: @IInspectable, I can understand that. I find CMake very convenient but in the past, I experienced pain in the head when configuring CMake for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use MFC with CMake, it must be installed via Visual Studio installer.

Unfortunately, I have only a German screenshot of the installer:

[image]

Since `REQUIRED` does not work with `FindMFC` this must be checked explicitly.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

project(mylib)

find_package(MFC)
if(NOT MFC_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "MFC was not found, please install Desktop development with C++ / MFC for newest build tools")
endif()

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED source.cpp)
```

The reason my VS project compiled before had nothing to do with MFC. The file that MFC includes was in the file system, but was not part of the VS project and was therefore not compiled there. That's why it ***seemed*** to work with the VS project.

Comment: *"Visual Studio Solutions are using some kind of embedded MFC"* - Not really. It's rather that MFC is deployed as part of Visual Studio. The header files and (import) libraries are installed into VS' installation directory. There's no supported way to install MFC as a free-standing library. As an aside: I don't believe that *"ASP.NET"* is a requirement, which the error message suggests.

Comment: @IInspectable I double check the ASP part and you are right, its in C++ desktop development. I will fix it, thanks! As for the headers, I had looked in the installation directory and found no file with the appropriate name. Therefore the suspicion that they are somehow embedded.

Comment: The ATL/MFC headers are installed in *"<VS Install Dir>\VC\Tools\MSVC\<version>\atlmfc\include\"*. Double-check whether you are looking at the right directory. Also note that you can [modify the language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#modify-language-packs) of your VS installation, without re-installing the whole thing (I don't know whether that applies to the Visual Studio Installer as well, though).

Comment: @IInspectable After the installation they were in this place, not before. BUT: I have noticed in the meantime that the file that includes the MFC header is located in the directory, but is not part of the VS project. In other words, the project does not use MFC at all. The directory was just not cleaned up. So there is indeed no ominous embedding.